# JS/JQuery - Split and map comma seperated string and join result depending on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

A ajax success returns me a comma seperated string (1,2,3) which I split and map to get the .text() of certain select options ... like this:

js:

```
success:function(data){

    console.log(data.added.allocatedTo);

    var selectText;
    var joinText;
    var stringResult = data.added.allocatedTo;
    var splitResult = stringResult.split(",").map(function(port) {

        selectText = $('.select-portfolio option[value='+port+']').text();

        joinText += selectText+',';

    }); 

    console.log(joinText);
}
```

The above provides me the following in the console:

Console:

```
1,2,3
undefinedPortfolio Test 01,
undefinedPortfolio Test 01,Portfolio Test 02,
undefinedPortfolio Test 01,Portfolio Test 02,Portfolio Test 03,
```

... but what I want is this:

```
Portfolio Test 01, Portfolio Test 02, Portfolio Test 03
```

... how can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` method on an array returns a new array using the given function to "map" an element (value) in that array to a new element (value) in the resultant array.

You can use the `join` method on arrays to reverse the split.

So what you want is this:

```
const joinText = stringResult.split(",")
                   .map(port => $('.select-portfolio option[value=' + port + ']').text())
                   .join(", ");
console.log(joinText);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.map` expects you to return a value from inside the function you provided to it:

```
const joinText = stringResult.split(",").map(function(port) {
  return $('.select-portfolio option[value=' + port + ']').text();
});
console.log(joinText);
```

(You're currently using the `.map` like a `forEach`, which isn't appropriate for what you're trying to achieve)

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly, you didn't initialize `joinText` to an empty string.  Simply declaring it as a `var` initializes its value to `undefined`.  When you add a string to it, it is cast into a string `"undefined"`, so now you have `"undefined" + "Portfolio Test 01,"`.

To fix, you can initialize it upon declaration:

`var joinText = '';`

** EDIT: Other answers are correct in that you are using the `.map` method as a `.forEach` or a `for` loop; however, I was just pointing out what was putting that `undefined` text in front of your string outputs.